# C# hiding with members

Tags: c#, inheritance, radix, derived, member-hiding

in the below example, what would happen?

```
class Base {
    public int abc = 3;
}

Class Derived : Base {
    public int abc = 2;
}

static void Main() {
   Derived blah = new Derived();
   Console.WriteLine(blah.abc);
}
```

I'm sure you would see '2' on your console, but what I'm reading (and seeing) opposes that...

Why would you see '3' instead of '2'? I thought members of derived classes 'hid' the same members of base classes...

Answer (score 10):

Well, you have a few compiler errors, but here is a corrected version based on your example.

```
class Base {
    public int abc = 3;
}

class Derived : Base {
    public int abc = 2;
} 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Derived foo = new Derived();
    Console.WriteLine(foo.abc);
    Base bar = new Derived();
    Console.WriteLine(bar.abc);
}
```

The first line will output a `2`. The second line will output a `3`. The reason why is because, unless you explicitly override a member of a base class, it will only apply to instances of the concrete class.

In your derived class, you're essentially using the [`new` modifier keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) without explicitly using it. The `new` keyword *hides* a base member, however if the concrete class is cast as its base type, the new property doesn't get used and can't be accessed until it is "cast-down" to the concrete class again.

In the second example, the `Derived` class is cast as a `Base`, so it will use the `Base` `abc` property. If you were to use the [`override` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx), then the second line would also output a `2`.

**Edit:** Keep in mind that in order to be allowed to use `override` on the `Derived` class, you need to mark `Base.abc` with the [`virtual` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx). Also, you can't make [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) `virtual`. You need to use [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) to use the `virtual` keyword. You shouldn't be exposing fields to begin with though, so this is generally never a problem.

Comment: Well, I thought this ages ago but I always get:

"error CS0106: The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item"

Comment: You need to add `virtual` to the base class' property in order to use `override` on a derived class.

Comment: @Dan: Just makes it worse: 

The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item
The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this item

Comment: Yeah. You can't make a field `virtual`. You should be using Properties instead of exposed fields. Making fields public is generally bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the obvious and numerous errors in your code :O, your assertion that "I'm sure you would see '2' on your console" is correct, you will, and I do!

You should really user

```
class Derived : Base {
    public new int abc = 2;
}
```

if hiding the inherited value is your intention

Answer (score 0):

Of course you will see **2**. Why did you think that you will see 3 ?

But you will get a warning:

> 'Derived.abc' hides inherited member
>   'Base.abc'. Use the new keyword if
>   hiding was intended.

So you can solve it doing:

```
class Derived : Base {
    public new int abc = 2;
}
```